# Check the value of the input to be the same as a <p>

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple game to learn Decryption while learning js. 
So I have a word, the same word encrypted, and a textarea where the user can write the correct word. When you write the correct word in the textarea, the encrypted word should take the value of the word. 
It should be something like those sites you learn a language where you have to write the word you hear etc.
Here is my code:

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('ans');
var p = document.getElementById('word');
var right = document.getElementById('c');


inp.addEventListener('input', function(){
    if (right.textContent === inp.value) { 
     p.textContent = right.textContent
      };
});
```

```html
<p id="word">lhatci</p>
<p id="c">chat</p> <!--this will be hidden-->

<textarea id="ans"></textarea>
```

Comment: you have a typo it's `right.textContent === inp.value` not `textContext`